# Trying to assign time zone to airport code in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, timezone, lubridate

I'm looking to find the time zones for both destination and origin data from the nycflights13 dataset. I'm supposed to be mapping this onto a plot, but I'm stuck trying to figure this part out.

At the moment, my data looks like this:

```
  origin dest 
  <chr>  <chr>
1 EWR    IAH  
2 LGA    IAH  
3 JFK    MIA  
4 JFK    BQN  
5 LGA    ATL  
6 EWR    ORD
```

I know the airport data has time zones built into it, but I'm not sure how to translate that into something useful for this code. Thanks!

Comment: My answer addresses the first part (how to get the time zone for each of those), but what kind of plot do you expect to make? It's unclear what plot needs to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  left_join(select(nycflights13::airports, faa, origintz = tzone), by = c(origin="faa")) %>%
  left_join(select(nycflights13::airports, faa, desttz = tzone), by = c(dest="faa"))
#   origin dest         origintz           desttz
# 1    EWR  IAH America/New_York  America/Chicago
# 2    LGA  IAH America/New_York  America/Chicago
# 3    JFK  MIA America/New_York America/New_York
# 4    JFK  BQN America/New_York             <NA>
# 5    LGA  ATL America/New_York America/New_York
# 6    EWR  ORD America/New_York  America/Chicago
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(origin = c("EWR", "LGA", "JFK", "JFK", "LGA", "EWR"), dest = c("IAH", "IAH", "MIA", "BQN", "ATL", "ORD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```